# Cannot convert value of type 'inout NSNumber?' to expected argument type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>' error

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, nsurl

I have this script use to check whether the *downloaded file from `iCloud` is available or not. But unfortunately I encountered error `Cannot convert value of type 'inout NSNumber?' to expected argument type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>'` in some lines of code. Please help me to solve this issue because it is my first time to create a code to check whether the downloaded file is available in the icloud or not.

Please refer to the image below as sample of the error and also codes are available below for your reference. Hope you could help me. Thank you.

[Sample screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv1SG.png)

```
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------
// ダウンロードできるか判定 Judgment or can be downloaded
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

func downloadFileIfNotAvailable(_ file: URL?) -> Bool {
    var isIniCloud: NSNumber? = nil
    do {
        try (file as NSURL?)?.getResourceValue(&isIniCloud, forKey: .isUbiquitousItemKey)

        if try (file as NSURL?)?.getResourceValue(&isIniCloud, forKey: .isUbiquitousItemKey) != nil {
            if isIniCloud?.boolValue ?? false {
                var isDownloaded: NSNumber? = nil
                if try (file as NSURL?)?.getResourceValue(&isDownloaded, forKey: .ubiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey) != nil {
                    if isDownloaded?.boolValue ?? false {
                        return true
                    }
                    performSelector(inBackground: #selector(startDownLoad(_:)), with: file)
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you copied and pasted some really old code. Besides, this is Swift, not Objective-C. Do not use NSURL or `getResourceValue`. Your code should look more like this:

```
    if let rv = try file?.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isUbiquitousItemKey]) {
        if let isInCloud = rv.isUbiquitousItem {
            // and so on
        }
    }
```

And so on; the same pattern applied to other keys. Note that there is no `.ubiquitousItemIsDownloadKey` either. You can condense things like this:

```
    if let rv = try file?.resourceValues(
        forKeys: [.isUbiquitousItemKey, .ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey]) {
            if let isInCloud = rv.isUbiquitousItem {
                if let status = rv.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatus {
                    if status == .downloaded {

                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: actually I am converting an old ios app in objective c to swift. Some functions of the app are new to me that's why I tried to use a website to convert it. Thank you for help.

Comment: Don't use that kind of translator web site. And now you can see why! Instead, learn to read Objective-C and write Swift. :)

Comment: Yes I'll take note of that. May I request a reference of this answers you gave me so I can apply it to my code. Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a reference. Facts are facts.